# Groovy object array creation question

Tags: grails, groovy

why does this throw an exception?

```
messageSource.getMessage('UserService.msg.forgot.unknown', ["test@mail.com"], null)
```

unless I do this...

```
def Object[] args = ["test@mail.com"]
messageSource.getMessage('UserService.msg.forgot.unknown', args, null)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because ["test@mail.com"] evaluates to an ArrayList, not an array:

```
groovy:000> o = ["asdf"]
===> [asdf]
groovy:000> o.getClass()
===> class java.util.ArrayList
```

OTOH your declaration creates an array of Objects:

```
groovy:000>  Object[] args = ["asdf"]
===> [Ljava.lang.Object;@14e113b
```

and the method you're calling needs an array. You can create an array using `as`:

```
Object[] args = ["asdf"] as Object[]
```

The Groovy creators made a point of making higher-level data structures like lists idiomatic, while arrays are present for interoperability with Java.

In his interview in *Coders at Work* Guy Steele talks about choices made in designing a language:

> "There's this Huffman encoding problem. If you make something concise,
>   something is going to have to be more verbose as a consequence. So in
>   designing a language, one of the things you think about is, 'What are
>   the things I want to make very easy to say and very easy to get
>   right?' But with the understanding that, having used up characters or
>   symbols for that purpose, you're going to have to make something else
>   a little bit harder to say."

It certainly looks like Groovy made lists more concise, with the side effect that arrays became more verbose.

Comment: makes sense, but seems to make the method a hassle to use, I guess I expected it to be more "groovy"

Comment: You could change it to ["test@mail.com"].toArray(). Not much better but at least it's inline.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan has already (correctly) explained the reason for this behavior at the language level. I just want to move one abstraction level up: Why are you using Spring's `MessageSource` directly, in the first place? In Grails there is a [`message` tag](http://grails.org/doc/1.1.1/ref/Tags/message.html), that wraps the message source:

```
g.message(code: 'UserService.msg.forgot.unknown', args: ["test@mail.com"])
```